Jenkins build history cleared unexpectedly
I'm using Jenkins 2.426.3.
I'm using a freestyle project and build retention policy is configured as follows:

Strategy: log rotation (only possible choice)
Days to keep builds: 10
Max # of builds to keep: 10
Days to keep artifacts: 10
Max # of builds to keep with artifacts: 10

I noticed the successful builds are kept less than a few hours.
I often go back to check the job only to find build history is empty.
Only the aborted builds are kept.
See also this question of mine. I suspect the issue might be due to some server-side housekeeping.

You have both the number of builds and duration criteria. It's whichever one is met first. If you have 10 runs within 10 minutes the 11th run will trigger cleanup for the first one, even if it's only 10 minutes old.

What you're describing is the expected behaviour. I haven't been able to fill the build history at all as it constantly gets cleared.

Also one strange thing is that I had taken the precaution of clicking "keep this build forever" but it wasn't kept at all.
